# Partially correct?Totally correct?Deterministic?Determined?Terminating? What do these adjectives mean for an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, programming-languages

These terms are often used to describe algorithms but I'm not really sure what they mean. I would like to see more examples of what each one is like and how they can be identified. Can anyone please provide a thorough explanation or any links/books that can help me understand these terms better? thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a reference to where you encountered these terms (in particular *partially correct*, *totally correct*, and *determined algorithm*).

Comment: that's true but also a bit difficult to do, as I'm studying programming in a German university and I came across these terms in the lecture notes, so I would find it a lot easier if there was a thorough explanation of these terms in English. The course is "Introduction to Programming" and we covered these terms under the topic "characteristics of algorithms"

Answer (score 3):

An algorithm is correct if it returns the intended output for all possible input instances.

As far as I know *partially correct* does not have any standard accepted meaning. If I was forced to assign a meaning to it, I would take it to mean that the algorithm returns the correct output for **some** input instances, although this is a very weak requirement...

Similarly, I'm not sure why one would need to specify that an algorithm is *totally* correct... that's probably just an alias for the definition of correct I gave above.

A *deterministic* algorithm is an algorithm that does not have access to any random bits, i.e., its execution is completely determined by the input instance.

I've never heard the concept of *determined* algorithm.

Terminating simply means that, for every input, the execution of the algorithm ends after some finite number of steps.
To be pedantic, some definitions require algorithms to always terminate in a finite number of steps. It is possible that the term algorithm you encountered was used in a more relaxed sense that also encompasses non-terminating procedures.

Comment: thank you! I appreciate that you took the time and effort to explain this. I tried to take "determined" as a direct translation of the term "determiniert" (the original note where I came across these concepts was in German ) If you can, could you perhaps provide a link to a website/youtube video or even book, that you might have used to learn about this? I'm trying to find some English resources that explain this concept thoroughly.

Comment: Partial correctness means that the algorithm produces the correct output of it terminates. To prove correctness, you have to prove partial correctness and that your algorithm halts.